# No Stack Trace using JCL in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, exception, stack-trace, jedi-code-library

We have a project which we converted from Delphi 2007 to Delphi XE. In the 2007 version we used the JCL's debugging features to have a stack trace when an Exception appears. In fact we used the JCL's standard *ExceptionDlg* wizard, which relies on the following line to get the Stack Trace:

```
StackList := JclLastExceptStackList;
```

This thing used to work in Delphi 2007 but not anymore in XE (it throws a *'blank'* stack).

If we replace that thing with a classical

```
   StackList := JclCreateStackList(false,0,Caller(0,false));
   lTemp := TStringList.Create;
   StackList.AddToStrings(lTemp,true,true,true,true);
   ShowMessage(lTemp.Text);
   lTemp.Free;
   Stacklist.Free;
```

...it works (hence we have the correct setings WRT to maps etc.), but (unfortunatelly) it shows the **present** stack trace (which, of course, leads to the exception dialog) and *not* to the stack trace of the **last** exception.

Any ideas how to fix this?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

Did you call `JclStartExceptionTracking`?

It seems this method is responsible for hooking up exceptions in the first place and adding a notifier.

```
function JclStartExceptionTracking: Boolean;
begin
  if TrackingActive then
    Result := False
  else
  begin
    Result := JclHookExceptions and JclAddExceptNotifier(DoExceptNotify, npFirstChain);
    TrackingActive := Result;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I did. In fact it is called automatically in the generated routine.